# Callback from adapter to activity in monodroid

Tags: android, gridview, xamarin.android, xamarin

So I have a listview and a gridview in my activity. Both have custom adapters. If a DragAction.Drop is performed I show a alert to confirm the action. If the user confirms this I will change some data in de database. Now the data is changed I need to refresh the listview. The method already exists but is part of the activity. I perform the alert and other actions that need to be done on drop in the adapter. So I need to tell the activity that the actions for the drop are completed. So the activity can call the refresh method.

This is my code from the DragAction.Drop in the adapter:

```
case DragAction.Drop:

                    truckNumber = e.Event.ClipData.GetItemAt (0).Text;
                    truckLabelText = e.Event.ClipDescription.Label;


                    AlertDialog.Builder alertBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder (context);
                    alertBuilder.SetTitle ("Please confirm");
                    alertBuilder.SetMessage ("Are you sure you want to assign Truck: " + truckNumber + " to Dock: " + dockName.Text + "?");
                    alertBuilder.SetPositiveButton ("Yes", async delegate {

                        currentTruck.SetText (truckNumber, TextView.BufferType.Normal);
                        truckLabel.SetText (truckLabelText, TextView.BufferType.Normal);

                        await _DataLayer.changeTruckStatusCode (Convert.ToInt32 (truckNumber), 3);



                    });

                    alertBuilder.SetNegativeButton ("No", delegate {

                    });
                    alertBuilder.Show ();


                    e.Handled = true;

                    break;

                }
            };

            dockName.SetText (item.name.ToString (), TextView.BufferType.Normal);
            currentTruck.SetText ("", TextView.BufferType.Normal);
            truckLabel.SetText ("", TextView.BufferType.Normal);

            return view;

        }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a simple interface.

```
public interface DragCompletedListener{
    void onDragComplete();
}
```

then, in your grid adapter prepare one member variable:

```
private DragCompletedListener dragCompletedListener;
```

prepare setter method:

```
public void setDragCompletedListener(DragCompletedListener dragCompletedListener){
    this.dragCompletedListener = dragCompletedListener;
}
```

Let your activity implemented DragCompletedListener.

and add your listener at the place you create your grid view adapter:

```
MyGridViewAdapter adapter = new MyGridViewAdapter();
adapter.setDragCompletedListener(this);
```

In your switch statement, add a call:

```
if (dragCompletedListener != null){
    dragCompletedListener.onDragCompleted();
}
```